# What are the .js files to include while using Jquery's Round corner plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, rounded-corners

I want to know the list of files to included while using jquery's round corners plugin. And how to use the functions in that Javascript. I need a round corner in my website with pure css and Javascript without images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include the jquery core library and corners plugin. Then use `corner()` method on items you want to have rounded corners. You will find more details about possible options of the plugin [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corner.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.roundedCorners').corner();
});
</script>
```

I suggest that you move the last part to a separate file and include it just like core library or corner plugin.